# Reflection in C# -- want a list of the data types of a class' fields

Tags: c#, reflection, types, field

My C# class MyClass (below) has members a, b, c, d, e, and f.

I'd like to use reflection to obtain a list of the data types of those members;
for example (borrowing from Python notation):  [ char[], ushort, char, byte, uint, ulong ].

```
class MyClass
{
    public  char [ ]    a ;
    public  ushort      b ;
    public  char        c ;
    public  byte        d ;
    public  uint        e ;
    public  ulong       f ;
}

class MainClass
{
public static void Main ( string [] args )
    {
        // get an array (or some kind of list) of MyClass' fields' data types ...
        // for example:  { char[], ushort, char, byte, uint, ulong }

        // I've tried the following, but can't get a column of just the data types, alone ...
        MemberInfo[] theMemberInfoArray = typeof(MyClass).GetMembers() ;
        foreach (MemberInfo mi in theMemberInfoArray)
            if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
                    Console.WriteLine ( "<" + mi.MemberType + ">\t"
                    + "<" + mi.GetType() + ">\t"
                    + "<" + mi.Name + ">\t" + mi ) ;
    }
```

}

Program output appears as below:

```
<Field> <System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo> <a>     Char[]  a
<Field> <System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo> <b>     UInt16  b
<Field> <System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo> <c>     Char    c
<Field> <System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo> <d>     Byte    d
<Field> <System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo> <e>     UInt32  e
<Field> <System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo> <f>     UInt64  f
```

I would like program output to appear as:

```
<Field> <System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo> <a>     <Char[]>     Char[] a
<Field> <System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo> <b>     <UInt16>     UInt16 b
<Field> <System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo> <c>     <Char>       Char   c
<Field> <System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo> <d>     <Byte>       Byte   d
<Field> <System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo> <e>     <UInt32>     UInt32 e
<Field> <System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo> <f>     <UInt64>     UInt64 f
```

Comment: In your post the actual output and what you say you want the output to be are identical.  I assume you want something other than what you posted, so please edit your question to clarify what your desired output actually is.

Comment: You have to indent by four to keep format. I've done it for you. BTW, it's called "Reflection", not "introspection".

Comment: I don't understand the difference between the two outputs. The desired output is just repeating column 4 without the angle brackets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this is how I did it, you want the FieldType which actually returns a Type instance.

```
var members = typeof(TestMe).GetFields().Select(m => new 
                                         { 
                                             Name = m.Name, 
                                             MemType = m.MemberType, 
                                             RtField = m.GetType(), 
                                             Type = m.FieldType 
                                         });

foreach (var item in members)
    Console.WriteLine("<{0}> <{1}> <{2}> <{3}> {3} {2}", item.MemType, item.RtField, item.Name, item.Type, item.Type, item.Name);

public class TestMe
{
    public string A;
    public int B;
    public byte C;
    public decimal D;
}
```

This is the output:

```
<Field> <System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo> <A> <System.String> System.String A 
<Field> <System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo> <B> <System.Int32> System.Int32 B
<Field> <System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo> <C> <System.Byte> System.Byte C
<Field> <System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo> <D> <System.Decimal> System.Decimal D
```

Comment: Thank you for this idea.  I had to modify it a bit to get it to work for me, but the idea came from you -- thanks again.


  FieldInfo [ ]  fieldInfoArray  = typeof(MyClass).GetFields() ;
  
  List <System.Type> fieldTypeList = new List <System.Type> ( ) ;

  foreach ( FieldInfo fieldInfo in fieldInfoArray  )
   fieldTypeList.Add ( fieldInfo.FieldType ) ;
   
  foreach ( System.Type type in fieldTypeList  )
   Console.WriteLine ( type ) ;

Comment: no problem. btw if you just want a list. you could use the .ToList() method in Linq like so:
 List<Type> list = typeof(TestMe).GetFields().Select(m => m.FieldType).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that MemberInfo has the information you want.  You might want to look at `GetFields()` and the `FieldInfo` class, or `GetProperties()` and the `PropertyInfo` class.

`GetMembers()` returns all fields, properties and methods, so if your class contained these they would be enumerated as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the Name property off of FieldType, which is available via FieldInfo.  You'll need to cast MemberInfo to a FieldInfo first:

```
foreach (MemberInfo mi in theMemberInfoArray)
{
    if (mi.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = mi as FieldInfo;
        Console.WriteLine(fi.FieldType.Name);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Char[]
UInt16
Char
Byte
UInt32
UInt64
```

Comment: Thanks!  I wish I could accept multiple answers, since your idea is also a good one.

Answer (score 0):

mi.Name is bringing back want you want, you jsut need to change your COnsole.WriteLine to print it again

Comment: I suspect you might have misunderstood me.  I'm wanting a list of the *datatypes*, not the field names.  For example, I'm wanting a list [  char[], ushort, char, byte, uint, ulong  ], a list that I can use programmatically, and not just display on the screeen.

Comment: So, in your loop where you're writing them to the console, add the types to a List<Type> using Type.GetType(mi.Name)

Comment: Sorry, instead of mi.Name you want mi.GetType()

Comment: mi.GetType() returns System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo not the actual Type of the field.