# c# generic type class cannot get the property value

Tags: c#, object, generics, reflection, field

Using c# reflection to get & set the value of the generic fields inside a generic object. But I cannot find any way to **get the property value of these fields**. The code example below:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
   public bool IsUpdated { get; set; } 
}

public abstract class ValueObjec<T>
{
   public string InnerValue { get; set; } 
}

public class ItemList: ValueObject<ItemList>
{
   public Foo<string> FirstName;

   public Foo<string> LastName;
}
```

**Problem**
Getting the 'null' item at the line (*).

itemField.GetType() always return the **System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo** type but not the **Foo** type.

I already tried using itemField.FieldType.GetProperty("IsUpdated"), it worked when returned the correct property. But threw an error **"Object does not match target type."** whenever call GetValue() method 
**itemField.FieldType.GetProperty("IsUpdated").GetValue(itemField, null)**

Much more appreciated if getting help from anyone!

```
var itemList = new ItemList();
foreach (var itemField in itemList.GetType().GetFields())
{
    var isUpdated = "false";
    var isUpdatedProp = itemField.GetType().GetProperty("IsUpdated"); // (*) return null from here
    if (isUpdatedProp != null)
    {
        isUpdated = isUpdatedProp.GetValue(itemField, null).ToString();
        if (isUpdated == "false") isUpdatedProp.SetValue(itemField, "true");
    }
}

foreach (var itemField in itemList.GetType().GetFields())
        {
            var isUpdated = "false";
            var isUpdatedProp = itemField.FieldType.GetProperty("IsUpdated");
            if (isUpdatedProp != null)
            {
                isUpdated = isUpdatedProp.GetValue(itemField, null).ToString(); (*) // throw error "Object does not match target type"
                if (isUpdated == "false") isUpdatedProp.SetValue(itemField, "true");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just as an aside, why are you converting everything to strings, instead of just using the `bool` value?

Comment: You probably meant `itemField.FieldType` / `itemField.PropertyType` instead of `itemField.GetType()`; hard to tell because `itemType` isn't actually defined in your code

Comment: Basically, it would be a lot easier to help you if you'd provide a [mcve] rather than just a snippet which wouldn't compile. We can't tell which errors are in your real code and which are just ones you've added when writing the question.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I suspect a typo in `foreach ( var itemList ... ` which I think should be `foreach ( var itemField ... `

Comment: Inherited properties are not returned by `GetProperty` unless you use the `FlattenHierarchy` binding flag:  `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy`

Comment: @ Marc Gravell @HimBromBeere Sorry! Updated the question

Comment: Have you looked at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104105/reflection-in-c-sharp-want-a-list-of-the-data-types-of-a-class-fields?

Comment: @HimBroomBeere the problem comes from itemField.GetType(), it doesn't return the correct type, just System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo type

Comment: @Kasguest "the problem comes from itemField.GetType()" - well, yes: as already said: you **shouldn't be using that**.

Comment: Are you looking for implementing object change tracking? You might want to take a look at https://github.com/mfidemraizer/trackerdog

Answer (score 5, accepted):

let's unpack this one thing at a time:

```
var isUpdatedProp = itemField.GetType().GetProperty("IsUpdated");
```

You should *never* need to use `.GetType()` on a member; you want `.FieldType` or `.PropertyType` (for properties). And `nameof` is great:

```
var isUpdatedProp = itemField.FieldType.GetProperty(nameof(Foo<string>.IsUpdated));
```

(`string` here is a dummy)

Then:

```
 isUpdated = isUpdatedProp.GetValue(itemField, null).ToString();
```

It isn't `itemField` that is your object - that's whatever the value of `itemField` *on that object* gives you. So pass that in; and treat the result **as a boolean**, if possible:

```
var isUpdated = false;
object foo = itemField.GetValue(itemList);
...
isUpdated = (bool)isUpdatedProp.GetValue(foo, null);
```

Finally:

```
if (isUpdated == "false") isUpdatedProp.SetValue(itemField, "true");
```

Once again, the object is `itemList`, and the property isn't a `string`

```
if (!isUpdated) isUpdatedProp.SetValue(foo, true);
```

---

It would be easier if you made `Foo<T> : IFoo` where `IFoo` is a non-generic interface:

```
interface IFoo { bool IsUpdated {get; set; } }
```

Then it becomes:

```
var foo = (IFoo)itemField.GetValue(itemList);
if(!foo.IsUpdated) foo.IsUpdated = true;
```

---

Finally, note that `FirstName` and `LastName` **will be null** if you haven't assigned them anything.

Comment: Thanks for your guide, really specific. Trying it!

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `FieldType` property instead of `GetType()` at `itemField` to get `Foo` type.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.fieldtype(v=vs.110).aspx

**EDIT:**
You must get the instance of the field type

```
var foo = itemField.GetValue(itemList);
var isUpdated = isUpdatedProp.GetValue(foo);
```

Final result should be like this:

```
var itemList = new ItemList();
foreach (var itemField in itemList.GetType().GetFields())
{
    var isUpdatedProp = itemField.FieldType.GetProperty("IsUpdated"); 
    if (isUpdatedProp != null)
    {
        var foo = itemField.GetValue(itemList);
        isUpdated = (bool)isUpdatedProp.GetValue(foo);
        if (!isUpdated) isUpdatedProp.SetValue(foo, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: using itemField.FieldType.GetProperty("IsUpdated"), it just returned the correct property. But threw an error "Object does not match target type." whenever call GetValue() method itemField.FieldType.GetProperty("IsUpdated").GetValue(itemField, null)

Comment: Just use `GetValue(itemField)` instead of `GetValue(itemField, null)`

Comment: It throws an exception or what? Compare the result with `string.Equals`

Comment: @Kasguest The `itemField` is not a instance of `Foo` that's why throws that exception.

Answer (score 1):

Let me throw my two cents on trying to give you another point of view to solve the problem.

I wouldn't use *reflection* for this: why don't you type those objects with interfaces?

```
public interface IUpdatable
{
     bool IsUpdated { get; set; }
}

public interface IManyUpdatable 
{
     IEnumerable<IUpdatable> Updatables { get; }
}

public static class UpdatableExtensions 
{
     public static void ToggleUpdated(this IUpdatable updatable) 
     {
          if(updatable != null)
               updatable.IsUpdated = !updatable.IsUpdated
     }

     public static void ToggleUpdatables(this IEnumerable<IUpdatable> updatables)
     {
          foreach(var updatable in updatables) 
                 updatable.ToggleUpdated()

     }
}

public class Foo<T> : IUpdatable
{
   public bool IsUpdated { get; set; }
}

public class ItemList: ValueObject<ItemList>
{
   public Foo<string> FirstName;

   public Foo<string> LastName;

   IEnumerable<IUpdatable> IManyUpdatable.Updatables => new [] {  FirstName, LastName }
}

// ... somewhere in your code base:

itemList.ToggleUpdatables()
```

I'm not sure if I've caught the idea, but it seems like you're overengineering and bypassing typing for no reason!

Comment: thanks for your idea, but I have to use reflection to solve the problem

Comment: @Kasguest BTW, for me your current questions seems to be an XY problem. Who knows if you explain your problem instead of your attempted solution I can convince you to avoid reflection in many cases :D