# Getting column names dynamically in SSIS script component acting as Destination

Tags: c#, ssis

Ok, I am writing an avro file using SSIS script component as a destination. Since AVRO needs a schema as well, I need to define the schema. It works fine when I define the schema manually. But I have 10-12 data flow tasks and I do not want to write the schema explicitly. I am trying to see if I can use the BufferWrapper which is auto generated to see if I can read from there but I can't and it always returns blank.

I have tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104105/reflection-in-c-sharp-want-a-list-of-the-data-types-of-a-class-fields) and also read up [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getfields?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#overloads).
But everything returns blank.

I have also come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28416273/apply-row-transformation-for-multiple-input-columns-in-script-transformation). Could that be the reason and if that explanation in the answer posted there is correct, isn't this possible?

So, in my 
public override void PreExecute(), I have something like this:

```
Schema = @"{
                        ""type"":""record"",
                        ""name"":""Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro.Specifications.Counterparts"",
                        ""fields"":
                            [
                               { ""name"":""CounterpartID"", ""type"":""int"" },
                               { ""name"":""CounterpartFirstDepositDate"",  ""type"":[""string"",""null""] },
                               { ""name"":""CounterpartFirstTradeDate"",""type"":[""string"",""null""] },
                               { ""name"":""ClientSegmentReportingID"",""type"":[""int"",""null""] },
                               { ""name"":""ClientSegmentReportingName"", ""type"":[""string"",""null""] },
                               { ""name"":""ContractID"", ""type"":[""int"",""null""] },
                               { ""name"":""ContractFirstDepositDate"", ""type"":[""string"",""null""] },
                               { ""name"":""ContractFirstTradeDate"",""type"":[""string"",""null""] },
                               { ""name"":""ContractClosingOffice"",""type"":[""string"",""null""] },
                               { ""name"":""LeadCreationDate"", ""type"":[""string"",""null""] },
                               { ""name"":""ContractCountryOfResidence"", ""type"":[""string"",""null""] }
                            ]
                    }";

}
```

Instead of manually defining all this schema, I am checking if I could generate it out of the BufferWrapper but this returns blank:

```
var fields = typeof(Input0Buffer).GetFields().Select(m => new
{
    Name = m.Name,
    Type = m.FieldType
}).ToList();
```

Also, if I just do this, that also returns blank

Type myType = typeof(Input0Buffer);

```
// Get the fields of the specified class.
FieldInfo[] myField = myType.GetFields();
```

Earlier I was putting these new methods in Pre-Execute but then thought, maybe the buffer isn't initialized by then , so I moved that to Input0_ProcessInputRow method and making sure that it is triggered only once using a counter variable and making this code run only when counter=0, but even that returns blank.

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{

    if (counter == 0)
    {
        Type myType = typeof(Input0Buffer);

        // Get the fields of the specified class.
        FieldInfo[] myField = myType.GetFields();
     }
  //Processing logic
 }
```

Isn't it possible because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28416273/apply-row-transformation-for-multiple-input-columns-in-script-transformation)?

As it talks about it being protected and also not accessible from outside that autogenerated class.

Comment: If you are creating a table only once I would write the code in the database instead of in c#.  You can use SQL Server Management Studio and using the Explorer you can right click on a database/table and then use the option to CREATE a table definition to see an example of the code.

Comment: Hi, I am not creating a table in the database. I am writing an AVRO file which requires a schema.I have OLEDB source which gets the data from SQL server and intention is to write to AVRO files from that. And as I said, I am trying to make this dynamic as this is not the only AVRO file I am going to create. There will be 20 others. So, I do not want specific definitions.

Comment: The schema format is JSON so any Net class/library that can generate JSON will wok.  See Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Avro

Comment: The question is not about JSON or AVRO. The question was about how to dynamically get the list of columns from the script component in SSIS InputBuffer and to use that to generate the schema for AVRO. The point of interest was to dynamically determine the input columns from InputBuffer of SSIS. anyways, I have found the answer and will post it.

Comment: You can get information from c# instead of using a script with the GetSchema Method : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.getschema?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found the answer here: https://waheedrous.wordpress.com/2014/02/24/ssis-global-replace-for-all-columns-using-a-script-component/

I can finally get the list of columns and datatypes from within the script component. I will only run it the first time (using a counter variable).